# Can I bind a single property in an ObservableCollection to ListView in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

My ViewModel contains an `ObservableCollection<TDL>`.

Each item is an instance of TDL:

```
public class TDL
{
    public string DataFile { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Items { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want all the names to be displayed in a ListView.
Can I bind only the `Name` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<TDL>` needs to be set as `ItemSource` of `ListView`. Property You like to have as displayed one, needs to be defined in `<ListView.View>` attribute, as presented below:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding NameOfObservableCollectionProperty}"....>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Name"
         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```